# How to store rich content in database?

Tags: mysql, database, markdown, richtext

This question is not about particular database engine, it's about actual content.

For example, frontend uses some kind of WYSIWYG editor (CKEditor, for example). It's easy to store everything what user types in editor, but this can potentially break design (unclosed tag) or add security issue ( tag). Also, there can be images and we can not simply store it in the same field.

We can circumvent most design/security issues using markdown, but how to store files/images alongside with text?

Should I create another table?

```
posts
   id
   text
post_images
    post_id
    image_id
    image_path
```

And inside post text have something like this

```
Hello, this is [image_id=22][/images/dgdgsdg.jpg] my image
```

Or there are other proven solutions?

All big social networks allow some kind of formatting with attached files, but how store it without headache?

Answer (score 1):

> We can circumvent most design/security issues using markdown

That is not true. Markdown can contain inline-HTML and you still need to validate/clean the generated HTML. Use the sanitizer-functions of your web framework.

Usually you'd just store the images on your server, the HTML (or markdown) contains the image path. You could also change the filename to a hash of the entire file. Again, usually there are plugins that handle this sort of thing for you (e.g. [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for Ruby on Rails).